# sorted strings return "none"

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to work with `list.sort()` method. For some reason, the result comes back as `None`, even though the lists do have values. In other usages with that method it worked well, and I can't find any difference in the use of the method.

The code I was writing was the solution for a simple exercise:

> Given a list of strings, return a list with the strings in sorted
>   order, except group all the strings that begin with 'x' first.
>
> e.g.
>   ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'] yields ['xanadu', 'xyz',
>   'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
>
> Hint: this can be done by making 2 lists and sorting each of them
>   before combining them.

My code:

```
def front_x(words):
    """ +++your code here+++ """
    x_list = []
    rest_list = []
    for word in words:
        if word[0] == 'x':
            x_list.append(word)
        else:
            rest_list.append(word)
    x_list = x_list[:].sort()
    rest_list = rest_list[:].sort()
    return [x_list, rest_list]
```

`x_list` and `rest_list` have the right values when the `for` loop is done, and after the sorting action they return `None`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

`sort()` does its work in place. There's no return value.

```
x_list.sort()
rest_list.sort()
```

There is a `sorted()` method that returns a new list. Perhaps that what you're thinking of?

```
x_list = sorted(x_list)
rest_list = sorted(rest_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sorted(x_list)` and `sorted(rest_list)` instead.

```
x_list = sorted(x_list)
rest_list = sorted(rest_list)
return [x_list, rest_list]
```

Answer (score -1):

Updating your code:

```
def front_x(words):
    """ +++your code here+++ """
    x_list = []
    rest_list = []
    for word in words:
        if word[0] == 'x':
            x_list.append(word)
        else:
            rest_list.append(word)
    x_list[:].sort()
    rest_list[:].sort()
    return [x_list, rest_list]
```